# Probability "at least" help!

Tags: probability

I would like to verify is my reasoning here is right. Thanks.

The example says:

"The residents of a town can be quite suspicious, especially when it comes to government conspiracies. On the question of whether the alien is part of a government effort in which the proof of intelligent life on other planets is hidden, the proportions of residents with varying opinions are given in the table.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline \text{Opinion}&\text{Proportion} \\
\hline \text{Very likely}&0.24\\
\hline \text{Slightly likely}&0.24 \\
\hline \text{Unlikely}&0.4\\
\hline \text{Other}&0.12\\
\hline
\end{array}

What is the probability that the selected person will find at least a slightly likely if the alien is part of a government effort in which they have hidden proof of the existence of intelligent life on other planets?"

Because it says at least that's the same as “greater than or equal to”. So that is the probability of slightly likely or more right? I believe that the probability of at least slightly likely is the sum of the probability of slightly likely and very likely, which is 0.48.

Will appreciate knowing if I'm right or not. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that’s the correct interpretation.